# Returning results from multiple rows into separate variables with one query

Tags: mysql

Question: What is the quickest way to assign values from multiple rows of a single column into separate variables?

Using `MySQL 5.6`, I have a table that stores data in regular time intervals.  In the insert trigger, I am attempting to detect when, among other similar things, a "peak" in the values has occurred, defined as two consecutive increasing values to a highest value, followed by two consecutive decreasing values.

Because there are several similar calculations to perform on the same data, I am first retrieving the values from a column for the last five rows into variables.  I have the ID numbers of the rows.

One way to do this would be individual `SELECT` queries for each ID.  However, I would like to consolidate them into a single query for speed, since the data will be entered into the database in blocks of 40k rows at a time.

Individual Selects:

```
SET currentValue = (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `tableid`=currentID);
SET prev1Value = (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `tableid`=prev1ID);
SET prev2Value = (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `tableid`=prev2ID);
SET prev3Value = (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `tableid`=prev3ID);
SET prev4Value = (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `tableid`=prev4ID);
```

I know another way to do this would be using joins on the same table.  However, this seems like this could be a slow way to go about it.  Is there a faster way to do this without using JOINs?  Thanks.

Multiple JOINs:

```
SELECT a0.`value`, a1.`value`, a2.`value`, a3.`value`, a4.`value`
        INTO currentValue, prev1Value, prev2Value, prev3Value, prev4Value
        FROM (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `tableid`=currentID) AS a0
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `tableid`=prev1ID) AS a1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `tableid`=prev2ID) AS a2
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `tableid`=prev3ID) AS a3
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `tableid`=prev4ID) AS a4
```

Another thing I thought of is something like:

```
SELECT IF(`tableid`=currentID, `value`, NULL)
        , IF(`tableid`=prev1ID, `value`, NULL) 
        , IF(`tableid`=prev2ID, `value`, NULL) 
        , IF(`tableid`=prev3ID, `value`, NULL) 
        , IF(`tableid`=prev4ID, `value`, NULL) 
        INTO currentValue, prev1Value, prev2Value, prev3Value, prev4Value
        FROM `table`
        WHERE `tableid` IN (currentID, prev1ID, prev2ID, prev3ID, prev4ID);
```

But I haven't tested it yet.

For now I am going to go with the `JOINs` until everything is in place, and I can test the IF statement model.  However, if someone knows that isn't going to work or has another method that would work better, I would appreciate it.  Also, would putting this into a VIEW help with the speed of the query?

Thanks.

Comment: You should try the `JOIN`. I'm not sure about MySQL, but most databases have pretty impressive optimization.

Comment: If the data is inserted in 40k line blocks, I wouldn't do this in a trigger. Rather after the whole insert do a run over the data and detect accordingly. That way you will only go through the 40k rows (plus 4 if detecting also from old data), now you would go through 40k selects, each one selecting one new row and four old ones, that you could already have in your variables.

Comment: So then, and this is where my inexperience with JOINs is showing, if I need to handle a situation where there are fewer than 5 rows in the table, when the data is first being collected, would the INNER JOIN handle that and not crash trying to, say,  assign a value to prev4Value if the JOINed table contains no rows?  Or would I need to use a LEFT JOIN in that circumstance?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Eventually, once everything is in place, we will be doing row-by-row insertions of data, and then, to me, the trigger makes the most sense.  I suppose we could have the trigger in place for then and use a secondary procedure for the bulk inserts. However, I like to have code in one place, so that's why I have been leaning toward the trigger model.  Thanks for the recommendation, though.  This may be an instance where two procedures makes more sense.

Comment: @GordoFabulous Yes, then the trigger will be a good idea. And for the data not being there, a LEFT OUTER JOIN will produce NULLs for missing values, but INNER JOIN will just skip the data points where the previous values won't exist. Do note that LEFT JOIN is still an inner join.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen So, if I am understanding you correctly, the JOIN method as I have it, will simply skip the assignment of values.  If I switch it to a LEFT OUTER JOIN, then it will explicitly assign NULL values to the variables. That makes sense. Will there be any issue if, looking at the JOIN code, prev4ID is NULL or will the JOIN simply be skipped?

Comment: @GordoFabulous Yes, the current JOIN code will just skip any row where it can't find rows for each ID (curerntID, prev1ID etc) and you will not have any problems. If the IDs themselves are NULL, no row can be matched, so with INNER join there will be a skip, with OUTER join you will get a NULL in value since that row cannot be found. So the safest method is the current JOIN code since it will always return the values in the database (so if there are no NULLs there, you will never get NULLs as values)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Awesome. Thanks for the info. You cleared up my understanding of all of this greatly.  Much appreciated.